# What is the reason to write custom GetModuleHandle function?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, assembly, malware

I was looking at ZeuS malware, and I've come across this piece of [source code](https://github.com/Visgean/Zeus/blob/translation/source/client/core.cpp#L175):

```
HMODULE _getKernel32Handle(void)
{
#if defined _WIN64
  return NULL; //FIXME
#else  
  __asm
  {
    cld                    //clear the direction flag for the loop

    mov edx, fs:[0x30]     //get a pointer to the PEB
    mov edx, [edx + 0x0C]  //get PEB-> Ldr
    mov edx, [edx + 0x14]  //get the first module from the InMemoryOrder module list

  next_mod:
    mov esi, [edx + 0x28]  //get pointer to modules name (unicode string)
    mov ecx, 24            //the length we want to check
    xor edi, edi           //clear edi which will store the hash of the module name

  loop_modname:
    xor eax, eax           //clear eax
    lodsb                  //read in the next byte of the name
    cmp al, 'a'            //some versions of Windows use lower case module names
    jl not_lowercase
    sub al, 0x20           //if so normalise to uppercase

  not_lowercase:
    ror edi, 13            //rotate right our hash value
    add edi, eax           //add the next byte of the name to the hash
    loop loop_modname      //loop until we have read enough

    cmp edi, 0x6A4ABC5B    //compare the hash with that of KERNEL32.DLL
    mov eax, [edx + 0x10]  //get this modules base address
    mov edx, [edx]         //get the next module
    jne next_mod           //if it doesn't match, process the next module
  };
#endif
}
```

Logic is the following:

1. Read `fs` segment register (32-bit Windows stores TEB there)
2. Get pointer to `PEB`
3. Get pointer to `PEB_LDR_DATA` (containing information about loaded modules of the process)
4. Iterate through the `InMemoryOrder` list
5. Compare module name with `"kernel32.dll"` using custom homebrew hash function

Why wasn't the use of `GetModuleHandle` appropriate there?

Comment: Often malware is injected into a process in a way that makes it hard to link to external functions from Windows DLLs. Code like this may be written to avoid having to link to external functions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan on the other hand, relying on such cumbersome code may spot the malware because of important process's crash. His "hashing" function isn't that good, and if the process has a lot of (small) libraries loaded, then there will be a high risk of collision.

Comment: Anyway, the question is probably opinion based and should be closed, especially as you seem to want to turn it in to a discussion.

Comment: IInspectable is saying just the same as me in the answer that you accepted ....

Comment: "Hard to link" is a very broad term. IInspectable mention precise reasons

Comment: Linking Windows DLLs seems clear to me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think it's not that opinion-based because there is a very likely reason why it is *necessary* to do, namely because `GetModuleHandle` is itself inside `kernel32.dll` and you get a chicken-and-egg problem since you need the handle to `kernel32` in order to call the function you would need to find said handle in the first place, as IInspectable said.

Comment: @cherry as I also said, but that's just a guess because we know nothing about the malware

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code snippet is trying to get the module handle (i.e. base address) of *kernel32.dll*, presumably because it doesn't have a handle to this module yet. [GetModuleHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199.aspx) is exported from *kernel32.dll*. You cannot call a function when you don't know its address.